# auto scan for guice

Tags: java, jersey, guice, ioc-container

I have never used guice before, and I wanted to try it out on an example project with jersey based JAX-RS API backed by a service-bean. I followed this guide: http://randomizedsort.blogspot.de/2011/05/using-guice-ified-jersey-in-embedded.html and was able to bring it to work. My setup is very simple, a JAX-RS resource is invoked via Guice and has a field that is annotated @Inject and injected by Guice:

```
@Path("configuration")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Singleton
public class ConfigurationResource {

    @Inject
    private ConfigurationService configurationService;
```

So far so good, everything works like it should, besides following: I am using GuiceServletContextListener for setting things up and have to name each component explicitly:

```
@WebListener
public class GuiceInitializer extends GuiceServletContextListener{
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new JerseyServletModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {
                //resources
                bind(ConfigurationResource.class);

                //services
                bind(ConfigurationService.class).to(ConfigurationServiceImpl.class);

                // Route all requests through GuiceContainer
                serve("/management/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I find it pretty inconvenient to explicitly name all dependencies. I have worked with standalone jersey before and it's perfectly capable of auto-scanning for resources in defined packages. Also Spring and CDI are capable of mapping implementation to interfaces without need to explicitly name them.

Now the question part:

- is there any autoscan extension/setting for guice? I found some on the internet, but it's hard to tell which of them are still useable and uptodate.
- is there any other possibility to make configuration of implementations and resources more convenient?

thanks in advance.
Leon

Comment: Auto-scanning encourages developers to just add dependencies. One of the reasons I like Guice is that, unlike Spring, every time you add a dependency, you're forced to ask yourself "Does this dependency make sense? Is it really necessary? Am I doing too much with this class?"

Comment: Hello @jerry-andrews, and thank you for the comment. Maybe I am misunderstanding Guice a bit. I wanted to use Guice as a possibility to use javax.inject semantics without the bloatedness of ejb/cdi or spring. Also I think in regard to your comment, that if I am writing a resource-class, annotating it @ Path and @ GET and what not, and implementing the logic behind them, I already answered the question "does this resource make sense", and being forced to add it to a configuration module is just a source for stupid errors...

Comment: You may want to look into using hk2 for that, it can scan your classes at build time with [hk2-metadata-generator](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b24/inhabitant-generator.html) and then you can use the [hk2 bridge](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b24/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/extras/ExtrasUtilities.html#bridgeServiceLocator%28org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator,%20org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator%29) to integrate it with the Jersey ServiceLocator

Comment: Lack of classpath scanning is an intentional design decision in Guice.  But there exist extensions like [Governator](https://github.com/Netflix/governator/wiki/Auto-Binding) to do it for you.

Answer (score 14):

I do not think Guice has built in support for someting like the component-scan of Spring framework. However, it is not difficult to simulate this feature in Guice.

You simply need to write a helper module like the following

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import org.reflections.Reflections;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * To use this helper module, call install(new ComponentScanModule("com.foo", Named.class); in the configure method of 
 * another module class.
 */
public final class ComponentScanModule extends AbstractModule {
    private final String packageName;
    private final Set<Class<? extends Annotation>> bindingAnnotations;

    @SafeVarargs
    public ComponentScanModule(String packageName, final Class<? extends Annotation>... bindingAnnotations) {
        this.packageName = packageName;
        this.bindingAnnotations = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(bindingAnnotations));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        Reflections packageReflections = new Reflections(packageName);
        bindingAnnotations.stream()
            .map(packageReflections::getTypesAnnotatedWith)
            .flatMap(Set::stream)
            .forEach(this::bind);
    }
}
```

To component scan a package like `com.foo` and sub packages for classes carrying `@Singleton`, use it in this way:

```
public class AppModule extends AbstractModule {
   public void configure() {
     install(new ComponentScanModule("com.foo", Singleton.class));
   }
}
```